# Subtraction of two similar Meijer G-functions

Tags: special-functions

Can we get another Meijer G-function from the following subtraction?

$$
G^{0, 5}_{5, 2}\left(
z \left| 
\begin{matrix}
(1, a, b, c, d) \\
(e, f)
\end{matrix}  
\right.\right)
-G^{0, 5}_{5, 2}\left(
z \left| 
\begin{matrix}
(\frac{1}{2}, a, b, c, d) \\
(e, f)
\end{matrix}  
\right.\right)
$$